# How do you use induction on a recursive sequence using different variables?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion

I've been working on some recursive sequences for my Discrete class. I've understood most of them, but I've come to a new question which I'm confused about.

A sequence $C_{0}$, $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$ is defined by letting $C_{0}=3$ and $C_{k}=(C_{k-1})^{2}$ $\forall$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $k\geqslant 1$. Show that $C_{n}=3^{2^{n}}$ $\forall$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $n\geqslant 0$.

I am not completely sure where to start on this. Do we solve for $P(n)$ using the k equation?

$i.e.$ $C_{n}=(C_{n-1})^{2} \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{?}}{=} C_{n}=3^{2^{n}}$

I am not completely sure how to start the problem, but I think it should be relatively simple once I have some direction on what exactly I need to be doing.

Comment: The confusion is about using $k$ and then $n$ for the indices?

Comment: That's where the confusion was yes. Most of the sequences we've done has just been finding the previous terms and showing that it holds true.

Comment: That's all you had to do in here as well.. the symbol of the index is meaningless here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  Here's what it might look like with a few more words included for readability.

**Base case:**  For $n = 0$,
$$
C_0 = 3^{2^0} = 3^1 = 3.
$$
So, the formula holds in this case.

**Induction step:**  Suppose that formula holds for $n = k - 1$ (where $k \ge 1$):
$$
C_{k - 1} = 3^{2^{k - 1}}
$$
Now, use the recursive formula to establish the formula $n = k$:
$$
\begin{align}
C_k &= \left( C_{k-1} \right)^2 \\
&= \left( 3^{2^{k - 1}} \right)^2 \\
&= 3^{2^{k - 1} \cdot 2} \\
&= 3^{2^k}. 
\end{align}
$$
Bam.  You have shown that $C_n = 3^{2^n}$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: Excellent, this really helped me out. I was thinking of the base case backwards which is likely why I was confused. Thanks for the help.